# How to pass parameters in function that not limit the number of parameters?

Tags: c, linux, parameters

It come across to me that function like printf() have not limited the number of parameters.

But when debugging program on Solaris, I noticed it will push at most 5 parameters into stack, common register will be used if there are more than 5 parameters.

So what will happen if even common register is not enough in function like printf ? Did compiler do something for me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is controlled by the ABI for the platform.  If there are more parameters than fit in the registers, then they will be handled in a different way.  There isn't a simple upper limit on the number of arguments that can be passed, so the compiler and the ABI define a mechanism that works on the hardware in question.  What works on SPARC does not necessarily work on, for example, Intel IA32.

Answer (score 0):

Normally platforms where the ABI uses registers for argument passing switch to a different calling convention for variadic functions, whereby everything is passed on the stack. This is why the C standard assigned **undefined behavior** to calling a variadic function without a prototype; without a prototype, on such platforms the compiler will generate an incorrect call.

It should be noted that some platforms use more complicated (uselessly complicated, I would say) methods of passing arguments to variadic functions, such as constructing a sort of linked list and passing a hidden pointer to that list, which the implementation of `va_start` is then somehow able to obtain. As a programmer, you should just treat the whole `stdarg.h` stuff as a black box that does what's expected, and pray that you never have to see the gorey details of some of the uglier implementations...